# Drag sibling element along with the current element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am in a situation where I need to drag an element along with it's sibling. The pattern of draggable elements will be as

```
<ContainerDiv>

 <Element1 draggable={true} />
 <Sibling1 draggable={true} />

 <Element2 draggable={true} />
 <Sibling2 draggable={true} />

 <Element3 draggable={true} />
 <Sibling3 draggable={true} />

</ContainerDiv>
```

I can't change the structure to wrap the element & sibling under one div. When user drags `element1`, `sibling1` should also be dragged along with it.

Here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-drop-crt7k?file=/src/Editors/renderWE.jsx).

Files:

```
editors.jsx - container
renderWE.jsx - element
renderBlock.jsx - sibling
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using `insertBefore()` node method in combination with a react trick. What I did was, on the drag start, I have stored the next sibling of current drag in the parent component or container where the drag over method is defined. As soon as the drag over is triggered, I first insert the dragging element and then insert the sibling element.

I know this is not the best solution, but this can be useful for me for the layer-1. I will think about the optimized approach in layer 2 and make an EDIT - 2.
[image]